# How to get characters from string to byte array?

Tags: android, arrays, string, byte

I have a string which contains elements of byte array such as "[B@42b19e58" which I have to convert back into the byte array.

Can someone please suggest me a method to do so?

Here, I don't have to convert a string to byte array. I already have byte array elements in the string, I just have to put them back to the array.

Comment: This depends on how you encoded your byte array as a string.

Comment: @KevinRobatel I don't have to convert a string to byte array. Read the question again before commenting.

Comment: How did the byte array get into the string? Show us this part of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
String str= "Convert Java String";
byte[] byteArray = str.getBytes();
```

Comment: I already have byte array element in a string. I just have to put it back to put them back to array.